# Omit null values in json response from Nancy FX

Tags: json, nancy

I am trying to create a REST service using Nancy FX in a C# environment. I can easily do a Response.AsJson and it all looks good. But I want the response to omit any properties that are null.

I have not been able to figure out how to do this yet.

Could someone point to me towards a help document or a blog post somewhere, that explains how to do this.

Thanks,
JP

Answer (score 3):

I would create a dynamic anonymous type and return that. So let's say you have a `User` object like this:

```
public class User 
{
   public string Id { get; set; }
   public string FirstName { get; set; }
   public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

You want to pass back an instance of this type as a JSON response so you will have some code like this:

```
Get["/user/{userid}"] = parameters =>
{
    var user = UserService.GetById(Db, (string)parameters.userid);
    if (user == null) return HttpStatusCode.UnprocessableEntity;

    return Response.AsJson(user);
};
```

But you don't want to return the `User` instance, instead you want to return an separate instance of a `dynamic` type that will only implement a property if the property value is not `null` for a given instance.

So I would suggest code something like this:

```
Get["/user/{userid}"] = parameters =>
    {
        var user = UserService.GetById(Db, (string)parameters.userid);
        if (user == null) return HttpStatusCode.UnprocessableEntity;

        dynamic userDTO = new ExpandoObject();
        userDTO.Id = user.Id;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(user.FirstName)) userDTO.FirstName = user.FirstName;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(user.LastName)) userDTO.Lastname = user.LastName;

        return Response.AsJson((ExpandoObject)userDTO);
    };
```

**Note 1**
You don't need to test for the `Id` since that is implied by the successful return of the `User` instance from the database.

**Note 2**
You need to use a `dynamic` type so you can include *ad hoc* properties. The problem is that  extension methods cannot accept dynamic types. To avoid this you need to declare it as an `ExpandoObject` but use it as a dynamic. This trick incurs a processing overhead but it allows you to cast the dynamic to an `ExpandoObject` when passing it in to the `AsJson()` extension method.